# Html Div (with tags and Hindi Unicode) to PDF in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, unicode, html-to-pdf

i want to export HTML `<div>` with content in Hindi (Unicode characters) to PDF in ASP.NET using C#. I've tried many different third party HTML to PDF conversion tools, such as nReco, evopdf, hiqpdf,... None of them are working properly in the sense that the Hindi text either isn't shown, or the resulting text isn't rendered correctly. For instance, if I have the text `"न्‍यायालय,विरूद्व,डब्‍ल्‍यु"` in Unicode, the characters are rendered incorrectly.

Comment: Very few PDF tools support Devanagari script. As far as I know, only iText 7 supports it in combination with the closed source pdfCalligraph add-on. There's an example in the [FAQ](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/which-languages-are-supported-pdfhtml) of the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/). The examples are in Java, but it's very easy for a .NET developer to port them to C#.

Comment: Also check out the [white paper about pdfCalligraph](https://developers.itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/Whitepaper_pdfCalligraph_2017.pdf). Different Indic languages are supported because the Indian government is using iText to create birth certificates, marriage certificates, etc in the local language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an HTML file `devanagari.html`:

```
<body>
<div>न्‍यायालय,विरूद्व,डब्‍ल्‍यु</div>
</body>
```

And I converted this file to PDF using [iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET) + [the pdfHTML add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML) + [the pdfCalligraph add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph).

You can see the result in the following screen shot:

[image]

To make this work, I first loaded my iText 7 license key to activate iText 7 and the twoo add-ons:

```
LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(System.getenv("ITEXT7_LICENSEKEY") + "/itextkey.xml");
```

In C#, you'd need something like this (see [How do I load a license key?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/license-key-frequently-asked-questions/how-do-i-load-license-key)):

```
LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile("path/to/itextkey.xml");
```

Then I ran this line of code:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest));
```

In C#, this would be something like:

```
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(src, dest);
```

where `src` refers to your HTML, and dest to the resulting PDF.

As far as I can tell from the screen shot, the content is rendered correctly. Most other tools will render the text like this (if they render anything at all):

[image]

Obviously, that is incorrect because no ligatures were made.

For more info about converting HTML to PDF with iText, please consult the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-1-hello-html-pdf). For instance: if you want to use a different font than the default font that is shipped with pdfHTML (FreeSans), you should consult [chapter 6: Using fonts in pdfHTML](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-6-using-fonts-pdfhtml).